# Need help understanding convoluted ActionScript

Tags: flash, encryption, actionscript

I come across this ActionScript snippet which I coudln't understand. Can anybody help me? Especially this line:

```
(((_local3 >>> _local2[((_arg1 + 1) + ((_local4 - (_local4 % 3)) / 3))]) & 0xFF) ^ (_local2[_arg1] ^ 13592211)).writeByte(!null!);
```

The whole function:

```
public function _StrPool170(_arg1:int):string{
    var _local2:* = new array(13592197, 2171943, 3679800, 2570278, 13592202, 7370616, 3374196, 13592216, 8355402, 7955555, 2830635, 6842988, 6447188, 3761774, 721203, 13592222, 7957577, 3616104, 2963757, 7958082, 4013869, 474940, 13592223, 6055787, 7043424, 8348261, 2897452, 7299657, 6908003, 4983814, 13592216, 6710339, 3222382, 6319147, 8283995, 6644332, 6825336, 747108, 13592203, 7765363, 2105456, 2693170, 13592198, 8089726, 2960765, 8025659, 1381752, 13592199, 6387064, 8025452, 8075900, 1340262, 13592221, 7169858, 8216683, 3419755, 7038254, 3565152, 918582, 13592202, 8024180, 3372641, 13592196, 7634554, 3766383, 1536634, 13592193, 8158079, 8156027, 7831419, 8220988, 3281535, 13592198, 8158565, 2960760, 8025659, 1381752, 13592192, 8026979, 8155518, 4028540, 8289392, 13592197, 8355430, 7828091, 3962722, 13592192, 8026979, 7501694, 4026983, 8289392, 13592199, 8223844, 8092025, 7896438, 1326705, 13592194, 7895393, 8289404, 8222835, 7487348, 1145982, 13592223, 6644860, 6447969, 6448480, 6515305, 6388094, 6516514, 4983905, 13592198, 6781541, 2960763, 7371579, 1381729, 13592203, 6977384, 2171254, 2693170, 13592198, 6781541, 2894971, 7371579, 1381729, 13592193, 6448993, 6447223, 8354682, 8220988, 3281535);
    var _local3:* = new ByteArray();
    if (!false) {
        var _local4:* = 0;    
        (((_local3 >>> _local2[((_arg1 + 1) + ((_local4 - (_local4 % 3)) / 3))]) & 0xFF) ^ (_local2[_arg1] ^ 13592211)).writeByte(!null!);
    };
    _local4++;

    return ((_local2[_arg1] ^ 13592211));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that this is the result of decompiling some obfuscated ActionScript. The decompiled code doesn't make any sense because of the obfuscator.